# Как оптимизировать запрос

Tags: mysql, запрос, index

Добрый день, есть вот такая таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ip_city` (
  `ip_from` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ip_to` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `locid` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Индексы:

```
ip_from BTREE   ip_from
ip_to   BTREE   ip_to
ip_from_2   BTREE   ip_from, ip_to
```

И запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `ip_city` WHERE (`ip_from` < 2995257412) AND (`ip_to` > 2995257412)
```

Никак не могу добиться вменяемого результата, никакой индекс не цепляет.

Comment: А что значит "никакой индекс не цепляет"?

Comment: EXPLAIN показывает что никакой индекс не используется

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, вывод команды с explain

Comment: id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE ip_city ALL ip_from,ip_to,ip_from_2    1709292 Using where

Comment: Составной индекс тут точно использоваться не может, потому как он был бы полезен если бы ip_from проверялось на строгое равенство. в данном случае MySQL мог бы использовать любой один из двух индексов, но видимо он считает, что по заданному условию он отберет слишком много записей. А в таком случае работа по индексу будет медленнее полного сканирования таблицы. Что индекс был использован MySQL должен понять, что индекс селективен, т.е. по заданному условию (одному из двух указанных) будет получено ну скажем не более 1% всех записей. на условиях больше/меньше это малореально

Answer (score 3):

> Выборки из одной таблицы
>
> Возьмем таблицу пользователей с набором личной информации,
>   проиндексированную по адресу электронной почты. Вот пара простых
>   условий, которые могут получить преимущества от индексов:
>
> EmailAddress = 'vasya.pupkin@mail.ru' написал равно вместо LIKE так
>   как сам удивился результатам EXPLAIN'а, нужны дополнительные
>   исследования - точно определенное значение всегда имеет возможность
>   использовать индекс, сервер пройдется по дереву и получит точное
>   указание на запись или несколько записей в таблице. Сразу нужно
>   отметить, что, определяя колонку уникальной, автоматически создается
>   индекс по ней. Зачем? Иначе было бы накладно перед каждой вставкой или
>   изменением в таблице проверять все значения поля на соответствие
>   условию уникальности, а так можно быстро проверить существование
>   записи. EmailAddress LIKE 'vacya.pupkin@%' - частичное использование
>   индекса. Повторю, что должна быть определена крайняя левая часть и
>   только она может быть использована для поиска по индексам. Например,
>   для условия EmailAddress LIKE 'vasya.%@mail.ru' тоже будет использован
>   индекс, но в поиске в структуре индекса будет участвовать только
>   vasya., а остальная часть будет проверена последовательным
>   сканированием строк, найденных с помощью индекса. К этому примеру мы
>   вернемся при рассмотрении особенностей составных индексов. Те же
>   условия распространяются на операции с числами: равенство, больше,
>   меньше и другие. Нетрудно догадаться, что некоторые условия можно
>   привести к альтернативным выражениям с использованием элементарных
>   операций, например, BETWEEN, который тоже оптимизируется.

([ссылка на источник](http://xpoint.ru/know-how/MySQL/Optimizatsiya/Indeksyi))

В таком случае вы можете попробовать использовать директиву `USE INDEX` или  `FORCE INDEX`.

**UPD**

В качестве оптимизации также можете попробовать в запросе вместо выборки всех полей, `"*"`, перечислить только те поля, которые вам действительно нужны. Это сократит количество выбираемых и пересылаемых данных.

Comment: FORCE INDEX немного помогло

Answer (score 3):

Оптимизатор начинает использовать индексы только если по его предварительной оценке, количество записей в результате будет не более 30% от общего количества записей в таблице. Иначе, он абсолютно справедливо считает, что быстрее будет тупо перелопатить все записи таблицы не используя индексы.

> Индекс не будет использован, если использование индекса требует от
>   MySQL прохода более чем по 30% строк в данной таблице (в таких случаях
>   просмотр таблицы, по всей видимости, окажется намного быстрее, так как
>   потребуется выполнить меньше операций поиска).

Поэтому ставьте хоть FORCE INDEX или USE INDEX - быстрее не станет.